# Remove simpledb mapWith by meta programming in dev mode

Tags: grails, metaprogramming, grails-orm, amazon-simpledb

I am using simpleDB GORM with my grails application, though simpledb is great its a huge drag while in development mode, every click takes few seconds resulting in not so rapid development.

From what I understand simpleDB comes into action only if domain class has following two lines in code

```
String id
static mapWith = "simpledb"
```

So, my question is, is it possible to remove/hide these two declaration on the fly from domain classes depending on some kind of flag?

Same question asked differently,

Is there a way in Groovy, most probably meta programming, by which I can

- Remove a variable declaration from a class(Domain class actually)
- Remove static mapWith declaration from a class(Domain class again)
- Finally, is there a way to iterate through all my domain class and perform first two operations in bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove mapWith = "simpledb" it will be mapped with Hibernate, and it is probably not a very good idea to develop on Hibernate GORM in dev and SimpleDB GORM in prod mode - the biggest problem is that your application would behave very differently because SimpleDB is based on eventually consistency, and it means you would get nasty surprises when in production compared to good old consistent world of relational DB...

Thank you for using simpledb plugin!

Roman.

Comment: Hey Roman, I do understand the differences between simpleDb and RDBMS only problem with SimpleDb is that it gets so slow in dev mode even when making very simple changes. So I was wondering that I can use RDBMS in dev mode for the day and may be at the end of the day I can test everything again with SimpleDB turned on and may be even use selenium so I don't have to waste a lot of time.

Comment: Also just removing mapWith = "simpleDb" doesn't seem to work, I have to remove "String id" deceleration as well that too from all the domainClasses.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with simpleDB but I'm assuming that if your mapWith looked like:

```
static mapWith = ""
```

That simpleDB would not be used.

So you could add this to your Config.groovy:

```
environments {
    production {
        mapWith = "simpleDB"
    }
    development {
        mapWith = ""
    }
    test {
        mapWith = ""
    }
}
```

Then you could access the Config value from:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.*

static mapWith = ConfigurationHolder.config.mapWith
```

So then when you create a Production war you'll get "simpleDB" otherwise you'll get an empty string.  Here is a link to see how to use the Config.groovy: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#config

If I'm way off on how simpleDB works I apologize.

Comment: I have to add mapWith in each domain class, do you think that adding something in config.groovy will override what is specified in the domainclass?

Comment: Note: It appears that using the empty string doesn't work (at least in Grails 2.2.0). Instead, it should be `static mapWith = 'GORM'` if you want to just use the default. See [GrailsDomainClass.GORM](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/d9c23cfb10cf580db6c6fe8a5ff91d915e6e650d/grails-core/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsDomainClass.groovy)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but I came across this [link](http://code.google.com/p/simpledb-dev/) which claims:

> SimpleDB/dev provides a local SimpleDB server, so you can develop offline, without even currently having a SimpleDB account.

Comment: How does that answer the question asked?