# Migration from MongoDB to PostgreSQL Groovy Application

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, grails

I am working on migration of mongoDB to PostgreSQL on groovy application. I am new to groovy platform. In one of the groovy file their is :

static mapWith = "mongo"

I am exactly not clear what does it means. According to http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/mapWith.html

**mapWith**

> **Purpose**
>
> The mapWith static property adds the ability to control if a domain
>   class is being persisted.
>
> **Examples**
>
> ```
> class Airport {
>   static mapWith = "none"
>
> }
> ```

I also went through this question [Remove simpledb mapWith by meta programming in dev mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799361/remove-simpledb-mapwith-by-meta-programming-in-dev-mode)

and I got an idea that in my grails application,

static mapWith = "mongo"

might be using mongoDB plugin. I don't know I am correct or not. So what does I need to do with this line for PostgreSQL migration?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you have to remove the line, as for SQL-based GORM-ing the defaults are fine

Comment: Please can you explain more because I am getting errors on removing that line.

Comment: see this http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/latest/mongodb/manual/guide/gettingStarted.html#withHibernate